# Proxy pass on subdirectory not working

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I have an api running at http://127.0.0.1:9650. For example the following is giving a json object as response:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:9650/ext/health
```

I would like to make the following work at https://example.com/my-node/ext/health.

I have the following nginx configuration:

```
 location /my-node {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9650;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
```

but this does not seem to work (I am getting a 404)

I tried adding:

```
proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:9650 /my-node;
```

but no luck there either. Does anyone have a suggestion how I can solve this?

Comment: please share the complete details of `nginx -T -t`

Comment: You need to use `location /my-node/ { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9650/; ... }` - notice the `/` at the end of both the `location` and `proxy_pass` statements. See [the proxy_pass directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Comment: @RichardSmith yes that's it! it is working now. Thank you!. If you add it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `proxy_pass` **without** an **optional URI** (e.g. `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9650;`), the requested URL is passed upstream unmodified.

So `https://example.com/my-node/ext/health` is passed upstream to `http://127.0.0.1:9650/my-node/ext/health` - notice that the "/my-node" part remains intact.

---

Using `proxy_pass` **with** an **optional URI** within a **prefix** `location` will translate the requested URL by substituting the location prefix with the optional URI.

For example:

```
location /my-node/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9650/;
    ...
}
```

In this case, the optional URI is `/`, so `/my-node/` in the requested URL is replaced by `/` before passing upstream.

So `https://example.com/my-node/ext/health` is passed upstream to `http://127.0.0.1:9650/ext/health` - notice that the "/my-node" part has been removed.

See [the proxy_pass directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.